# java debugging doesn't show current line correctly

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans

I have a simple java class , and I set a break point at main method and step by  clicking 'step into' (netbeans ide).

Expected:

> green line goes to line `4` and `5` until loop ends

What happens:

> It stays at line `4`.

I can see in the console that the value of i get printed.
If i gets printed, that mean it should go to line 5 which is  `System.out.print(i+" > ");`.

Why it stays at line 4 until loop ends ?

Here is the preview:

[image]

[This is the code i'm debugging:](http://pastebin.com/XMp2FgPe)

```
2 | public class NewClass2 {
3 |     public static void main(String[] args) {
4 |         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
5 |             System.out.print(i+" > ");
6 |         }
7 |         System.out.println("end of the loop");
8 |     }
9 | }
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint at line 5 as well? On a side note, how do you make a gif like this? Looks really good..

Comment: @Gosu but i think it should go line by line .isn't it ? i don't think is this netbean dependent problem .

Comment: Haven't been debugging stuff for awhile now, but I think it only 'stops' at the lines with break points.. so if you want the debugging to 'pause' at both lines 4 and 5, you need 2 break points?

Comment: @Gosu, I don't think he needs 2 break points. Once a break point is met, he can choose to proceed line by line (breaking in every line) and that's what he seems to be doing. For some reason netbeans is not stopping as it should. I think it's netbeans specific.

Comment: @Codebender I _don't_ think this is NetBeans specific, but rather it is Java specific.

Comment: You can check with the other version of NetBeans, may be it's NetBeans Problem...

Comment: i think i only need one break point

Comment: @Codebender I see, I tried with 1 breakpoint in Eclipse.. and it works, not familiar with Netbeans..

Answer (score 6):

I have seen similar behavior to this before while using IntelliJ.  I believe what is happening is that the call to `System.out.println()` actually gets optimized during the build process.  As a result, the call to `System.out` doesn't actually exist once you have finished building the code.  And when you go to debug, the debugger cannot get a hook into this code because it is not really there in the form you see on the screen.

By the way, you should get a badge for posting a very nice animated GIF in your OP.  I think this is the first time I have seen this, and it worked very nicely in your question.

If you want to "trick" the IDE into being able to "see" the `System.out` call, you can try using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String stuff = "";
        System.out.print(i + " > " + stuff);
        stuff += "more stuff";
    }
    System.out.println("end of the loop");
}
```

Add your breakpoint right on the line with `System.out` and your NetBeans IDE *might* be able to see it.  I have tried something similar to this with IntelliJ with varying degrees of success.

Comment: that's interesting .is this NetBeans specific ? and how can i see correctly what line is being executing ? so if this is happening due to optimization this shouldn't be a netbean specific but some one has commented that it works in eclipse .so that mean eclipse don't optimize ?? or

Comment: just imagine i want to find a problem in a code snippets . so to correctly find what's going on i should change codes to trick the ide.that's is hurting .

Comment: Typically the problem you are trying to find _won't_ have to do with a `System.out` call, so the fact that the debugger may skip over this call is usually not a big problem.  Do you have a need to step into your call to `System.out`?  If not, I would forget about this, because for most of your regular code you will not see this behavior.

Comment: does different ides act different ?? is there any other way i can avoid this problem ?i like not to modify codes

Comment: I believe I have seen this in both Eclipse and IntelliJ; not sure about NetBeans, though it appears to be present there as well.  In your contrived example you have this problem.  If you edit your OP with your real code, maybe we can answer your real question.

Comment: that's my real code. i never new that's happens due to sout .but some times we can have code snippets that has this problem .instead of modifying codes is there any other way